# Github on Windows: two entries in Credential Manager, prompt to choose credentials to use

Tags: windows, git, github

Please bear with me that I ask here, but I struggle to find a better place to ask.

Recently, Github on my local PC started to ask me about the credentials to use, but it shows me 2 identical entries.

[image: Same git user names in Github account prompt]

In Windows Credential Manager, I see 2 entries for Github, one like `GITNAME@github.com`, the other just `github.com`:

[image: 2 entries in Credential Manager]

If I remove both entries from the Credential Manager, Github asks me to identify either via PAT, user name and password, or browser. I tried PAT and browser, in both cases the 2 entries are created and again Github asks me periodically to choose from the 2 identical identities.

I am clueless what the reason behind the behavior might be.

Comment: Try `git config -l | grep -i credential` in git-bash. Are there multiple different values about credential helper?

Comment: @ElpieKay There are 2 entries here, one for my Azure Git repos, the other one for github.com. [Here's a screenshot of the output](https://imgur.com/a/HRsgts6).

Comment: Is the last one `credential.<url>.username=<username>`? If so, remove it or comment it out, delete the entries in Manager and then try again.

Comment: No, there is no entry like the one you described.

Answer (score 0):

The error went away after logging out of all Git instances (Github.com and Azure), rebooting the system and then logging in again.